# More efficient way to run date/yyyy query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I use the following query quite a lot but am pretty sure there must be a more efficient way to do it.

Basically, I am counting the decades people were born in, from within a user table:

```
select count(*) as howmany, yyyy from bday where (((yyyy > '1949')
AND (yyyy < '1961')) AND (user_id = '63')) UNION
select count(*) as howmany, yyyy from bday where (((yyyy > '1959')
AND (yyyy < '1971')) AND (user_id = '63')) UNION
select count(*) as howmany, yyyy from bday where (((yyyy > '1969')
AND (yyyy < '1981')) AND (user_id = '63')) UNION
select count(*) as howmany, yyyy from bday where (((yyyy > '1979')
AND (yyyy < '1991')) AND (user_id = '63')) UNION
select count(*) as howmany, yyyy from bday where (((yyyy > '1989')
AND (yyyy < '2001')) AND (user_id = '63'))
```

Comment: doesn't it return 1 row with count=1 and yyyy for this particular `user_id`?

Comment: @deathApril No, the query runs perfectly showing a separate line with how many for each decade

Comment: so you don't have unique `user_id`s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can calculate the decade and use it to group the users:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(id) AS howmany,
    CEIL((`yyyy`+1)/10) AS decade,
    yyyy
FROM `bday`
GROUP BY decade
```

Comment: +1, although `yyyy DIV 10` would perhaps be slightly clearer (just IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

to count the decades people were born in:

```
select substring(yyyy, 1, 3) || '0''s' decade, count(*) howmany
from bday
group by decade
```